# Critical section doesn't work in onSensorChanged()

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-sensors

I'm new to Android development. I'm building a simple Android application which analyzes `accelerometer sensor` data and plays a sound with `MediaPlayer`. Code for `SensorEventListener` implementation:

```java
    class AccelListener implements SensorEventListener {
        boolean firstUpdate = true;
        volatile boolean stopped = true;
        private MediaPlayer mplayer;
            //some variables to store calculations

        public AccelListener(MediaPlayer mediaplayer) {
            mplayer = mediaplayer;
            mplayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    if (mplayer == mp) {
                        synchronized (AccelListener.this) {
                            stopped = true;
                        }
                        Log.d("MediaPlayer Callback", "stopped=" + stopped);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        updateAccel(event.values);
        if (isAccelChanged()) {
            Log.d("Accel Listener", "stopped_before=" + stopped);
            synchronized (this) {
                if (stopped) {
                    stopped = false;
                    firstUpdate = true;
                    mplayer.start();
                    Log.d("Accel Listener", "stopped_after=" + stopped);
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

The problem is that when I launch the application and start shaking the phone, the sound plays several times at the same moment. Audio file is about 3-4 seconds long, so there's no way it plays to the end and then reacts to the next shake.

Logcat shows the following:

```java
08-12 22:16:24.693: D/Accel Listener(5382): stopped_before=true
08-12 22:16:24.693: D/Accel Listener(5382): stopped_after=false
08-12 22:16:24.693: D/Accel Listener(5382): stopped_before=true
08-12 22:16:24.703: D/Accel Listener(5382): stopped_after=false
08-12 22:16:28.777: D/MediaPlayer Callback(5382): stopped=true
08-12 22:16:28.777: D/MediaPlayer Callback(5382): stopped=true
```

Critical sections in the `onSensorChanged()` and `onCompletion()` are locked on the same object (I make only one instance of `AccelListener` in the program), so there should be no parallel access to `stopped`.

Furthermore, this variable is declared as `volatile`, so anyone entering a critical should have a fresh, up-to-date value. But it seems like two different threads *actually enter the critical section simultanously*, both having the same flag value. How could this happen, and where am I wrong?

P.S. The guy over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993705/problems-with-onsensorchanged-method) seems to have the same problem, but none of the solutions for his case (like synchronizing on separate object or using the same instance of `MediaPlayer`) worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I didn't unregister `AccelListener`, and it seems like debugger don't properly stop running version of the program. Each consecutive `Run` command just started main activity, it instantiated `AccelListener`, registered it, and so on. Adding the following code fixed the whole thing:

```java
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensMgr.unregisterListener(grListener);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensMgr.registerListener(grListener,
            sensMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you enter inside of the "isAccelChanged() if", you are always starting the sound in the player within "onSensorChanged" regardless of the value of stopped (it is out of the if, and out of the synchronized block).

If you are sure you are have just one instance you can get rid of the "synchronized"s.

Check it out and respond back.

Comment: I supposed that **if (!stopped) {return;}** when **stopped=false** will just abort metod execution, making **mplayer.start()** unreachable. Removing synchronization didn't change anything, neither did moving **mplayer.start()** to critical section.

Comment: Ahh..yes right!..Should be unreachable. And true again, that means that from the "if" to the "Log.d" someone is changing the value of stopped. Pretty weird.
Can you share the final code you are using?

Comment: Updated code. I left `synchronized` blocks though, because the version without them was the one I started with, it doesn't help.

Comment: Mm..still struggling with that. I'll have to end up testing your code for real. Another workaround could be to stop listening for SensorEvent updates will your sound is playing. You can do so with register and unregisterListener.

Comment: sorry, I meant *while instead of *will.
Happy it helped.